# Postgres data still "in use" after server stop

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am running postgresql in a docker container. Now I wanted to add checksums to the database cluster. So I stopped the docker container and waited some time. But the pg_checksums tool is still complaining:
pg_checksums: error: cluster must be shut down

There is no postgres or similar running any longer, with docker or not.
Renaming the file postmaster.pid did not change anything.
What du I need to do to convince pg_checksums that it can savely work on the cluster data?
I'm using postgresql 12 and Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d on a CentOS 8 machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shutdown the **database** cleanly.  Shutting down the container itself apparently did not do that.  A tool which does not attach to PostgreSQL's shared memory has no way to know whether a database has crashed, or is still running.  So you need a clean shutdown.